# Why do I get Method “props” is only meant to be run on a single node. 0 found instead in unit testing?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I was creating unit tests for my modal component but when I run the tests I get `Method “props” is onlymeant to be run on a single node. 0 found instead.` Here is my test file's excerpt:

```
test('should contain input fields with appropriate labels', () => {
        expect(
            wrapper
                .find('Input')
                .at(0)
                .props().label
        ).toEqual('Current Password');
        expect(
            wrapper
                .find('Input')
                .at(1)
                .props().label
        ).toEqual('New Password');
        expect(
            wrapper
                .find('Input')
                .at(2)
                .props().label
        ).toEqual('Confirm New Password');
    });

    test('should contain input fields with appropriate placeholders', () => {
        expect(
            wrapper
                .find('Input')
                .at(0)
                .props().placeholder
        ).toEqual('Please enter your current password');
        expect(
            wrapper
                .find('Input')
                .at(1)
                .props().placeholder
        ).toEqual('Please enter your new password');
        expect(
            wrapper
                .find('Input')
                .at(2)
                .props().placeholder
        ).toEqual('Please confirm your new password');
    });

    test('should contain input fields with required props', () => {
        expect(
            wrapper
                .find('Input')
                .at(0)
                .props().required
        ).toEqual(true);
        expect(
            wrapper
                .find('Input')
                .at(1)
                .props().required
        ).toEqual(true);
        expect(
            wrapper
                .find('Input')
                .at(2)
                .props().required
        ).toEqual(true);
    });
});
```

And this is my component file that I want to test:

> class ChangePasswordModalRoot extends PureComponent {
>           form = FormBuilder.group(
>               {
>                   currentPassword: ['', [Validators.required]],
>                   newPassword: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern(RESET_PASSWORD_FORMAT)]],
>                   confirmPassword: ['', [Validators.required]],
>               },
>               { validators: checkIfMatchingPasswords('newPassword', 'confirmPassword') as ValidatorFn }
>           );
>
> ```
>     handleSave = () => {
>         const { onSave } = this.props;
>         const oldPassword = this.form.get('currentPassword').value;
>         const newPasswordLeft = this.form.get('newPassword').value;
>         const newPasswordRight = this.form.get('confirmPassword').value;
>         onSave(oldPassword, newPasswordLeft, newPasswordRight);
>     };
>
>     render() {
>         const { isShow, classes, onClose } = this.props;
>
>         return (
>             <div className={classes.container}>
>                 <FieldGroup
>                     control={this.form}
>                     strict={false}
>                     render={({ invalid }) => (
>                         <ModalDialog
>                             maxWidth="sm"
>                             isShow={isShow}
>                             disableSave={invalid}
>                             config={{
>                                 title: `New password`,
>                                 handleConfirm: this.handleSave,
>                                 handleCancel: onClose,
>                             }}
>                         >
>                             <div className={classes.defautlWrapper}>
>                                 <div className={classes.defautlWrapper}>
>                                     <FieldControl
>                                         name="currentPassword"
>                                         render={({ handler, errors, touched }) => (
>                                             <Input
>                                                 {...handler()}
>                                                 required
>                                                 touched={touched}
>                                                 label="Current Password"
>                                                 type="password"
>                                                 errors={errors}
>                                                 placeholder="Please enter your current password"
>                                                 maxLength={200}
>                                             />
>                                         )}
>                                     />
>                                 </div>
>                                 <div className={classes.newPasswordWrapper}>
>                                     <FieldControl
>                                         name="newPassword"
>                                         render={({ handler, errors, touched }) => (
>                                             <Input
>                                                 {...handler()}
>                                                 required
>                                                 touched={touched}
>                                                 errors={errors}
>                                                 type="password"
>                                                 label="New Password"
>                                                 errorMessages={DEFAULT_VALIDATION_ERRORS}
>                                                 placeholder="Please enter your new password"
>                                                 maxLength={200}
>                                             />
>                                         )}
>                                     />
>                                 </div>
>                                 <div className={classes.newPasswordWrapper}>
>                                     <FieldControl
>                                         name="confirmPassword"
>                                         render={({ handler, errors, touched }) => (
>                                             <div>
>                                                 <Input
>                                                     {...handler()}
>                                                     required
>                                                     touched={touched}
>                                                     errors={errors}
>                                                     type="password"
>                                                     errorMessages={ERROR_MESSAGE_NO_MATCH}
>                                                     label="Confirm New Password"
>                                                     placeholder="Please confirm your password"
>                                                     maxLength={200}
>                                                 />
>                                             </div>
>                                         )}
>                                     />
>                                 </div>
>                             </div>
>                         </ModalDialog>
>                     )}
>                 />
>             </div>
>         );
>     }
> }
> ```

Comment: you haven't shown us wrapper = .... ; if you are using shallow to create wrapper you might be missing dive() calls.

Answer (score 0):

Can you change `Input` to `input`

```
wrapper
    .find('input')
```